# Как задать время по своей локали в php?

Tags: дата, php, время

Нужно поменять часовой пояс. Как это сделать без изменений настроек сервера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

смотри тут http://itif.ru/ustanovka-vremennoj-zony-v-php-i-mysql/

Comment: Спасибо, мне подошла функция. Она мне как раз и была необходима.

Answer (score 2):

Для настроек временной зоны для конкретного сайта, необходимо в .htaccess добавить строку:

```
php_value date.timezone “Europe/Moscow”
```

Список временных зон можете посмотреть тут: http://php.net/manual/ru/timezones.php